# this.each is not a function in jqm widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have some trouble with my jqm widget.
When I do that `$("div[id=leftSideList]").leftlist('refresh')`, its work fine. But, if I wrap code below on constraction like this

```
function _list (key) {
            switch (key) {
                case 'leftlist':
                    return $("div[id=leftSideList]").leftlist;
                case 'rightlist':
                    return $("div[id=leftSideList]").rightlist;
            }
        }
```

and use `it _list('leftlist')('refresh')`. 
Its return me error Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the returned function (`leftlist` or `rightlist`) has lost its scope; `this` within the function no longer refers to the `div[id="leftSideList"]` element, hence the error.

You can fix this by using `$.proxy`, however it is incredibly ugly and not really a workable solution for a production setting:

```
function _list(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'leftlist':
      return $.proxy($("div[id=leftSideList]").leftlist, $("div[id=leftSideList]"));
    case 'rightlist':
      return $.proxy($("div[id=leftSideList]").rightlist, $("div[id=leftSideList]"));
  }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dx2oaynp/) - note this uses built in jQuery methods as you did not provide the source of `leftlist()` and `rightlist()`.

A much better solution would be to avoid this completely unnecessary abstraction entirely. It is offering you no benefit whatsoever, other than keeping the selected element consistent.

```
function _list(key, action) {
  return $("div[id=leftSideList]")[key](action);
}

_list('leftlist', 'refresh')
```

Finally note that using `div[id=leftSideList]` is redundant and slow. You can just use `#leftSideList` instead. The only reason you would use the attribute selector is if you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - which is invalid and an issue you should fix as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! It work exelent. And thank for advise about my code